# What are possible real use cases of the Emacs "psychotherapist" mode?

Tags: help, doctor

It is well known that when you type `M-x doctor`, a kind of AI program prompt you to write about your problems, as a psychotherapist does. Some said it's an easter egg, but [it seems it goes beyond the fun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA).

The manual says (33.2.8 in a 2007 paper edition):

> If using Emacs (or something else) becomes terribly frustrating and none of the techniques described above solve the problem, Emacs can still help you. First, if the Emacs you are using is not responding to commands, type C-g C-g to get out of it and then start a new one. Second, type M-x doctor RET. The Emacs psychotherapist will help you feel better.

Do you have real examples of people using the help of the psychotherapist? Is there use cases where it can really be used as a tool to solve problems? Do you have some stories about it here?

Comment: Why do you say what are possible real use cases of the emacs
psychoterapist mode?

Comment: IMO the psychologist could be rewritten to provide debugging assistance, like a "smart" version of edebug.  That would be a more or less complete rewrite, but it would be really cool!  And on-topic IMO.

Comment: For [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eliza stems from 1960s research in AI. It goes beyond the fun as far as AI research is concerned; it's wildly out of date, but still a common, reasonably fun programming exercise. As far as psychotherapy is concerned, it is about fun. It *can* alleviate frustration, but it isn't supposed to bring serious psychological help.

`doctor.el` *is* in the `lisp/play/` subdirectory.

Comment: I didn't believe it was designed to resolve psychological problems, but it can help a confused programmer to relax by having fun and "speak" about an encountered problem

Answer (score 4):

When life, the universe and everything is all getting too much, Emacs has 
`doctor.el` to help. To consult the doctor type

<kbd>M-x doctor</kbd>

The doctor is a psychoanalyst who will help you with your problems. It would spoil the fun and hurt your recovery to say too much here about how the doctor works. But when you’re ready to find out see [WikiPedia:ELIZA.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA)